# Google Docs Android app navigation top bar

Tags: android, navigation, toolbar, scrollable

Anyone has an idea of what controls does Google use on its Google Docs App top bar? I'm referring to the scrollable one with the Starred/All Items/Owned by me/Home labels that appears after you select an item on the home screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the ViewPager. You can find a good example of the ViewPager [here](http://geekyouup.blogspot.com/2011/07/viewpager-example-from-paug.html).